# Espacio en nombre de la propiedad de un objeto

Tags: javascript

Estoy consultando una api rest sobre precios de carburantes, y en el array que me devuelve, encuentro nombres de campos con espacios. ¿Cómo puedo consultarlos?

Ejemplo:

```
<div v-for="valor in valores">
  {{ valor.Municipio }} {{ valor.Horario }} {{ valor.Dirección }} => {{valor.PrecioGasoleoA}}
</div>
```

Mientras que el nombre del campo al que quiero acceder aparece en el objeto como "Precio Gasóleo A".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien puede indicarme como llegar a ese campo? Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes acceder o establecer las propiedades de los objetos en JavaScript mediante la notación de corchetes `[]`:

```js
let obj = {
  'clave con espacios': 99
}

console.log(obj['clave con espacios'])
```

Referencia: [Objetos y propiedades](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Trabajando_con_objectos)

Comment: Perfecto. Gracias!!